# über die Straße gehen vs die Straße überqueren

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, semantics

Haben die folgenden Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung?

1. Ich gehe über die Straße.
2. Ich überquere die Straße.

Laut vielen Wörterbüchern scheint es so.

Comment: Welchen Grund gibt es daran zu zweifeln? Was ist der Grund für diese Frage?

Comment: @Hubert Die Frage ist durchaus berechtigt.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ich glaube gern, dass eine solche Berechtigung existiert. Ich kann sie aber nicht erkennen. Daher frage ich danach. Ich habe nicht gefragt *»Gibt es einen Grund zu fragen?«* Ich habe gefragt: *»Was ist der Grund für diese Frage?«* Und diese Frage ist noch immer offen.

Comment: @Hubert Eventuell ist der Kontext (Grund) hier wieder einmal vom OP durch die Tags [tag:meaning-in-context] und [tag:semantics] _"verkürzt"_ dargestellt. Ich erlebe diese Art von "Kurzschluss" auch auf anderen Stack Exchange Seiten immer wieder.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich bin kein Muttersprachler, aber ich bin sehr sensibel mit Nuancen zwischen Ausdrücken und aus meiner Erfahrung bin ich ja ganz überzeugt, dass es in diesem Fall einen Unterschied gibt.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich gebe zu, dass der Tag  meaning-in-context hier vielleicht nicht der Beste ist, aber immer noch in einem bestimmten Sinne ja.Und im Fall des Tages semantics glaube ich, dass es schon ganz berechtigt ist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Haben die folgenden Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung?
>
> 1. Ich gehe über die Straße.
> 2. Ich überquere die Straße.

Nicht zwangsläufig (auch wenn eine äquivalente Verwendung möglich ist).

> > Ich gehe über die Straße.

Kann ebenso verwendet werden um auszudrücken, dass man die *Strasse* benutzt um von A nach B zu gelangen, im Gegensatz zu z.B.

> > Ich gehe über den *Feldweg*.
> >
> > Ich gehe über die *Wiese*.
> >
> > etc.

Während

> > Ich überquere die Strasse.

eindeutig impliziert, dass man von der einen auf die andere Strassenseite gelangt.

---

Das hängt letztendlich natürlich vom Kontext ab. So könnte es z.B. in einem Dialog heissen:

> > *X*: Ich nehme ab hier den Trampelpfad zum Kiosk.
> >     *Y*: Ich gehe (lieber) über die Strasse.

*"Ich überquere die Strasse zum Kiosk."* macht in o.g. Kontext keinen Sinn, es sei denn der Kiosk liegt genau auf der gegenüberliegenden Strassenseite (von *ab hier*).

Comment: Oder in schwach befahrenen Seitenstraßen über die Straße gehen, statt über den Bürgersteig.

Comment: Kontext ist wieder einmal König. "Ich gehe über die Strasse" ohne weitere Angaben und ohne Kontext ist mit Sicherheit synonym zu "'überqueren". Sagt man aber "Ich gehe von zu Hause aus über die Hauptstrasse nach Eisenach",  dann ist es synonym zu "benutzen". Ebenso, wenn alternative Routen im Kontext genannt wurden: "Entweder gehe ich durch den Wald oder...".

Comment: *überqueren* kann auch bedeuten, dass man eine Fußgängerbrücke benutzt, *über die Straße gehen* geschieht hingegen auf der Oberfläche. Das einfache *queren* ist hier besser.

Comment: Panta rei, Du hast recht. Es scheint aber, dass es einen anderen Unterschied gebe. Man könnte eine Straße überqueren, mit z.b. einem Fahrrad oder Rollschuhen, während das nicht der Fall wäre, wenn man "über die Straße gehen" benutzt.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, wenn mit "über die Straße gehen" "die Straße überqueren" gemeint ist, haben beide Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung ;-) 
Den Ausführungen von @πάντα ῥεῖ ist eigentlich nur noch hinzuzufügen, dass das Wort "überqueren" in der Alltagssprache kaum benutzt wird.

Comment: Ich glaube gar nicht, dass @πάντα ῥεῖ die Absicht gehabt hat, um zu zeigen, was du meinst. Auf jeden Fall hat er mehr Punkte hervorgehoben als nämlich zeigen, dass "überqueren" nicht sehr oft verwendet wird.

Comment: @Lalo: Richtig. Die Antwort von πάντα ῥεῖ ist klasse. Und ich habe eben noch einen zusätzlichen Punkt hervorgehoben :-)

Answer (score 0):

Der Unterschied ist, dass du im ersten Fall Fußgänger bist, im zweiten nicht notwendigerweise. Denn eine Straße kannst du z. B. auch mit dem Fahrrad überqueren.

Comment: "Gehen" benutzt man aber auch für viele Tätigkeiten, wie etwa mit dem Besen über etwas gehen oder mit dem Bleistift über die Abrechnungen, und so kann man auch mit einer Teermaschine oder einem Schneeräumkettenfahrzeug einmal über die Straße gehen. Oder man ist der Wind (poet.), und geht erst über's Meer, dann über die Straße.

Comment: @userunknown Ganz ehrlich: Ich hab' noch nie jemand weder mit einer Teermaschine noch mit einem Schneeräumkettenfahrzeug  über die Straße gehen sehen. Maximal gehen die Leute bei uns mit einem Hund über die Straße. Manchmal spät abends auch mit einem Affen, aber das nur im Schwäbischen.

Comment: @userunknown: Sagt ein in seinem Fahrzeug sitzender Schneeräumer wirklich _»Ich gehe über die Straße«_, wenn er von seiner Frau per Fon gefragt wird, was er gerade tut? Und was glaubt seine Frau, wenn sie diesen Satz von ihm hört?

Comment: Ist ein hypothetischer Fall. Er kann auch sagen "Ich stinke nach Fisch". Ich muss noch mal über meine alten Beiträge gehen, ich glaube da habe ich auch hypothetische Fälle. Handwerker gehen laufend über ihre Werkstücke, mit Sandpapier oder Lack. Den Jargon von Schneeräumdiensten oder Asphaltiermaschinenlenkern kenne ich nicht näher.

Comment: Merkwürdig. Das ist die einzige Antwort, die den Unterschied ohne Bla-Bla auf den Punkt bringt, und trotzdem hat sie zwei Abwertungen bekommen. Manchmal verstehe ich die Leute hier nicht.

Comment: @Pollitzer Du hast recht. Heute habe ich mit einigen Muttersprachlern über dieses Thema gesprochen, und sie haben gesagt, dass man "eine Straße mit dem Fahrrad" überqueren kann, aber nicht z.b. "über die Straße mit dem Fahrrad" gehen.